# Alphanumeric display - placement in memory

Tags: display

I have an alpha numeric display 32 rows x 80 char/row. What is placement in memory and physical address of character row 8 column 40?

Comment: You need more information:
1) Is each location just a character? Or a character plus its attribute/colour?
2) What is the start address of the display in memory?
3) How many "cells" are in each row? 80? Or more? (Many displays have scroll left/right memory)

Comment: 1) Yes 2) I don't know 3) Yeah, it's 80

Answer (score 1):

I'll use an `(x,y)` notation, where `x` is between `1` and `80`, and `y` is between `1` and `32`:

Work your way forwards. Assuming that the top left cell `(1,1)` is at physical memory address `0x0000` (*very* unlikely!) then the top left cell is at address `0x0000`. The one beside it `(2,1)` is at `0x0001`, and so on until the last cell `(80,1)` is at `0x004F`.

The next row starts at `(1,2)`, at address `0x0050`. That implies that the start of each row is `0x0050` further than the start of the previous row. I'll fast forward to row 8...

The eighth row starts at `(1,8)`, at address `7 * 0x0050`. Why 7? Row 1 was 0, so Row 8 is 7.

Column 40 is `(40,8)`, so you need to add 39 (`0x0027`) to the address. Why 39? Column 1 was 0, so Column 40 is 39.

So, in general, the physical address is `<start> + (y - 1) * 0x0050 + (x - 1)`.

For `(40,8)`, that would be `0x0000+(8-1)*0x0050+(40-1)`, or `0x0257`